# sort dictionary swift add keywords

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary

Hi when I tried to sort a dictionary I noticed that the output contains key: and value: words, how can get rid of it?
my code:

```
var x1=["c":30,"b":60,"a":40]
let dd=x1.sorted(by: {$0.0<$1.0})
print(dd)
```

the result was as follows:
[(key: "a", value: 40), (key: "b", value: 60), (key: "c", value: 30)]

I want to get rid of key: and value:. so I want my answer something like
[( "a", 40), ("b", 60), ("c",  30)]

my second question how to sort depending on value not on key.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example with `map` and `tuples`.

```
var x1=["c":30,"b":60,"a":40]

let mappedArray = x1.map{($0.key, $0.value)}.sorted(by: {$0.1<$1.1})

print(mappedArray)
```

Print

```
[("c", 30), ("a", 40), ("b", 60)]
```

Comment: that would be the solution... after getting the keys you can then sort them and put them into an array

Comment: @AlexWoe89 second question is to sort by value not key

Comment: @Oleg Gordiichuk ...wow ..thanks a lot ..you really helped me understand many things I wasn't aware of

Comment: @WISAM no problem